# Popup window link launching in window as well as in the browser tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, popupwindow, ui-sref

I'm working on a website built using Laravel and AngularJS.
I want a certain link to open in a popup window. 
The javascript code is

```
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'test','height=400,width=550');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
    }
```

and the link is

```
<a ui-sref="test({id:test.id})" class="btn btn-primary fright" onclick="return popitup(this.href)" oncontextmenu="return false;">Resume</a>
```

when I click on the button the popup works fine but the link also opens up in the tab where I clicked it, but I don't want it to.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: there aren't any errors in the console

Comment: Then make sure it is not Angular that decides where to go.

Comment: the link is dynamic ui-sref="test({id:test.id})" and the state routeprovider determines the link do i need to use another method for this?

Comment: I have no idea. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#ui-sref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess `ui-sref` will also bind a click-event and that event will trigger before yours.

You could skip the ui-sref and put the url in a data-attribute or inside the onclick-attribute. You could get the url using $state.href() instead. Then the problem may disappear.

**Edit**

You could bind it to a scope function and skip onclick all toghether. Something like this:

In the Controller (Also make sure you include $state in the controller first):

```
$scope.popitup = function(stateName, options) {
 var url = $state.href(stateName, options);
 newwindow=window.open(url,'test','height=400,width=550');
 if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

And in the HTML you invke the popuitup function with the state name and its parameters:

```
<a ng-click="popitup('test', {id:test.id})" 
   class="btn btn-primary fright" oncontextmenu="return false;">Resume</a>
```

Also see documentation for [state.href](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options).

Comment: then do i pass "test({id:test.id}) in the $state.href()?

Comment: I think you should use ng-click actually. Let me update my answer with that now when I'm on a computer and not a phone.

Comment: i added $state to the controller , copied the function in it and modified the hyperlink but nothing is happening on clicking it

Comment: Check the console. I just saw that I spelled `function` wrong. Could that be it?

Comment: i corrected that right after i copied it. also the console isn't showing any issues

Comment: Ok, try to debug the function using developer tools or console.log inside it to see if it comes there, you can also log the value of the url to see if it is correct.

Comment: turns out it was a cache issue with chrome the method works

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<a href="http://google.com" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://google.com','example','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Popup-window</a>


</body>
</html>
```

try this code for popup window and change google.com to you site